# Printing Lighter in the Zebra printer

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zebra

We are printing multiple labels to the zebra printer.
The labels printing in the printer is lighter.

We have tried to increase maximium printing darkness level to 30  in the printer setting but no luck.Is there any possiblities to make the print darker through the script.Please suggest any solution for the issue.

Attached the script for reference.

~CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMR
^PW406
^LL0203
^LS0
^FT8,48^A0N,17,19^FB390,1,0,C^FH^FDSafari Sunset Dress^FS
^FT117,199^A0N,17,16^FB173,1,0,C^FH^FD712732-006-0000^FS
^FT102,103^A0N,17,16^FH^FDUS (XS)   UK (XS)   DE(XS) ^FS
^FT15,124^A0N,17,16^FB180,1,0,C^FH^FDMade In India: ^FS
^FT37,124^A0N,17,16^FH^FD^FS
^FT94,24^A0N,14,16^FB242,1,0,C^FH^FDXXX Organization^FS
^FT13,82^A0N,17,16^FB380,1,0,C^FH^FDPrint/Pattern^FS
^BY1,3,41^FT64,171^B3N,N,,N,N
^FD7127320060000^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Thanks
Alex Jones AX

Answer (score 0):

~SD is the command to increase the darkness and, in your script, it is set to 15 which is an average value.
You can change it to ~SD30 but keep in mind that the higher the darkness, the higher is the chance to have a faulty printhead sooner than with an average value

Comment: Thanks Zrep.I will try and update you.